# cython running slower than numpy for distance calculation

Tags: performance, numpy, distance, cython

I'm trying to learn cython; however, I must be doing something wrong. This little piece of test code is running about 50 times slower than my vectorized numpy version of it. Can someone please tell me why my cython is slower than my python? Thanks.

The code calculates the distance between a point in R^3, loc, and and array of points in R^3, points.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def distMeasureCython(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] points, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] loc):
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef unsigned int L = points.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] d = np.zeros(L)
    for i in xrange(0,L):
        d[i] = np.sqrt((points[i,0] - loc[0])**2 + (points[i,1] - loc[1])**2 + (points[i,2]  - loc[2])**2)
    return d
```

This is the numpy code that it's being compared against.

```
from numpy import *
N = 1e6
points = random.uniform(0,1,(N,3))
loc = random.uniform(0,1,(3))

def distMeasureNumpy(points,loc):
    d = points - loc
    d = sqrt(sum(d*d,axis=1))
    return d
```

The numpy/python version takes about 44ms and the cython version takes about 2 seconds. I'm running python 2.7 on a mac osx. I'm using ipython's %timeit command to time the two functions.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the cython version (and I'm suprised it's as slow as it is).  However, you're not going to beat a properly vectorized numpy expression with cython. Cython is best (and generally quite good) for operations that can't be vectorized.  Also, you might speed up your numpy version slightly by using `d = np.hypot(*d.T)`.

Comment: Have you run `cython -a your_code.pyx` and viewed `your_code.html`?  That's a handy way to inspect the C code generated by cython, and find out how much has been translated to C and how much is still working at the Python level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to `np.sqrt`, which is a Python function call, is killing your performance  You are computing the square root of scalar floating point value, so you should use the `sqrt` function from the C math library.  Here's a modified version of your code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython
cimport cython

from libc.math cimport sqrt

DTYPE = np.float64
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_t
@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn of bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def distMeasureCython(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] points,
                      np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] loc):
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef unsigned int L = points.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] d = np.zeros(L)
    for i in xrange(0,L):
        d[i] = sqrt((points[i,0] - loc[0])**2 +
                    (points[i,1] - loc[1])**2 +
                    (points[i,2] - loc[2])**2)
    return d
```

The following demonstrates the performance improvement.  Your original code is in the module `check_speed_original`, and the modified version is in `check_speed`:

```
In [11]: import check_speed_original

In [12]: import check_speed
```

Set up the test data:

```
In [13]: N = 10**6

In [14]: points = random.uniform(0,1,(N,3))

In [15]: loc = random.uniform(0,1,(3,))
```

The original version takes 1.26 seconds on my computer:

```
In [16]: %timeit check_speed_original.distMeasureCython(points, loc)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.26 s per loop
```

The modified version takes 4.47 *milliseconds*:

```
In [17]: %timeit check_speed.distMeasureCython(points, loc)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.47 ms per loop
```

In case anyone is worried that the results might be different:

```
In [18]: d1 = check_speed.distMeasureCython(points, loc)

In [19]: d2 = check_speed_original.distMeasureCython(points, loc)

In [20]: np.all(d1 == d2)
Out[20]: True
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. I'm getting the run-times that you mention above too. Thanks for the tip about the html too. This is my first question, so am I supposed to close it now that it's resolved? Thanks for the help WW.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, it's the numpy.sqrt call in the code. However, I think one does not need to employ `cdef extern`, since Cython provides these basic C/C++ libraries already. (see [the docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html)). So you could just cimport it like this:

```
    from libc.math cimport sqrt
```

Just to get rid of the overhead.